# How to create an ImplicitRegion from a list of 2D coordinates

Tags: regions, computational-geometry

I have a set of (x,y) coordinates. How can I link them together to form an ImplicitRegion?

Comment: Do VoronoiMesh or DelaunayMesh create the type of region you're looking for? Those are mesh regions.

Comment: `Show[reg = ConvexHullMesh[data], Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[data]}]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit region for the convex hull:

```
SeedRandom[0];
data = RandomReal[10, {20, 2}];
bdy = ConvexHullMesh[data];
normals = Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[bdy, 1];
bpts = MeshCoordinates[bdy][[MeshCells[bdy, 1] /. Line[{p_, ___}] :> p]];
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   MapThread[
    Dot[##] < 0 &, {normals, Transpose@({x, y} - Transpose@bpts)}], 
   Evaluate@Join[{{x}, {y}}, MinMax /@ Transpose@data, 2]];
```

Visualization:

```
Show[
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@reg,
 Graphics[{PointSize@Large, Point@data, PointSize@Medium, Red, 
   Point@bpts}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
pts = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {20, 2}];
reg = DelaunayMesh[pts];
HighlightMesh[reg, {Style[0, {PointSize[Large], Yellow}], 
  Style[1, Cyan], Style[2, Pink]}]
```

[image]